# Recursive directory walk

Tags: cocoa

I am attempting to walk a directory within Objective C.  I can do this in Java, but how to do this in Objective C eludes me. I'm using XCode5 and trying to stay out of C++/C.

I have some, but so far, I am missing something.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPush:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Button Pushed");
    NSOpenPanel*    panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    [panel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
//    [panel setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES]; // not now
    [panel setMessage:@"Select one or more, files or directories."];

    [panel beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger result){
        NSLog(@"OPEN Pushed");
        if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {

            NSArray* urls = [panel URLs];
            [self parseArray:urls]; *// How do I use the URL?NSURL?
            // Need to know if selected is File or Directory.
            // If File, what is the file attributes
            // If Directory, list the contents of the directory: procedure to recursively handle*
}
```

Comment: Start with [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  Everything you need is there.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `-[NSFileManager enumeratorAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:errorHandler:]`. Apple's documentation, including some sample code, is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_26).